# What is the groundspeed history of an aviation of such as a Boeing plane?

Tags: groundspeed

I would like to see groundspeed data of civil aircraft for distances such as 300 miles. What could it look like for a popular model such as Boeing 737?

Comment: This is wildly broad, ground speed is affected by many things, like wind. I'm not exactly sure what you are asking either, what do you mean "changes during a civil aviation"?

Comment: If you're looking for a plot of ground speed over a 300 mile flight, you can find this on [flight tracking sites like FlightAware.](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/SWA375/history/20170605/1645Z/KLAS/KSAN/tracklog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're asking is to see groundspeed history of a certain type of aircraft, you can choose a type here:  [aircraft type airborne now](http://flightaware.com/live/aircrafttype/)

Then follow the links to see its flight track history as shown here: [Flight Aware Track History](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL1378/history/20170602/2029Z/KCLT/KPBI/tracklog)